# Connection types, http/ws/ipc

Tags: go-ethereum, websocket, ipc

I was wondering and couldn't find any docs regarding that, which connection is the fastest/has the least latency when querying the blockchain? From logical point of view I think IPC, but I'm not sure. My application is running in the same server that my node is.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally more efficient to use `IPC` for local communication rather than `HTTP` or `WebSockets` for remote communication.

It allows fast and efficient communication when the node and the application are located on the `same physical machine` or are connected via a `local network`.